# How long does the “new” indicator show up next to a task in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: task-list

When creating a task in SharePoint 2010, the "new" indicator is shown after creating a task. How long is this displayed and is the amount of time it is displayed configurable from the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it is displayed for 2 days. You can override it with STSADM:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287681(office.12).aspx

If you are using SharePoint 2010, you should also be able to override it using PowerShell.